# Calculate module constant in a function

Tags: elixir

I would like to put a heavy calculation for a module constant into a separate function, but this fails:

```
defmodule Test do
  @test calc_constant()

  defp calc_constant do
    # Calculation heavy task like building a translation table
  end
end
```

Can i somehow do this without having to write the whole calculation at the top of my module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can, but you should put the function inside *other* module.

```
iex(1)> defmodule A, do: def calc, do: 42
{:module, A, <<70, 79, ...>>, {:calc, 0}}

iex(2)> defmodule B do
...(2)>   @a A.calc()
...(2)>   def a, do: @a
...(2)> end
{:module, B, <<70, 79, ...>>, {:a, 0}}

iex(3)> B.a
42
```

The reason is: `@var` declarations are being fully expanded *on compilation stage*. While having the function inside the same module, you experience a chicken-egg problem.

---

*Sidenote:* if one has many constants to declare, the other way round would be to provide a module, that declares `__using__` macro and [`Kernel.use/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#use/2) it in your module like this:

```
defmodule HeavyConstants do
  defmacro __using__(_opts) do
    quote bind_quoted: [test1: heavy_calc1(), ...] do
      @test1 test1
      @test2 test2
      ...
      @testN testN
    end
  end
end

defmodule Test do
  use HeavyConstants

  # here you have all `N` `@test{1,2,...N}` on hand
end
```